# Google Sign In SDK instantiate VC is nil

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, cocoapods, google-signin

I've successfully integrated Google Sign In SDK with code. In my appDelegate I have the `didSignInFor` method:

```
func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInFor user: GIDGoogleUser!, withError error: Error!) {
    if let err = error {
        print("Failed to log into Google: ", err)
        return
    }

    print("Successfully logged into Google", user)

    guard let idToken = user.authentication.idToken else { return }
    guard let accessToken = user.authentication.accessToken else { return }
    let credentials = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(withIDToken: idToken, accessToken: accessToken)

    Auth.auth().signIn(with: credentials) { (user, error) in

        if let err = error {
            print ("Failed to create a Firebase User with Google account: ", err)
            return
        }

        guard let uid = user?.uid else { return }
        print("Successfully logged into Firebase with Google", uid)

        // this is not working
        // signInViewController.instantiateTabVC()

    }
}
```

`var signInViewController = SignInViewController()` is a global variable. `instantiateTabVC()` is declared in `SignInViewController()`:

```
    func instantiateTabVC() {
    let viewController: UIViewController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "TabViewController") as! TabViewController
    self.present(viewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

The Google user is successfully signed in, however when the app attempts to instantiate the `TabViewController` it is found nil. However, I know that it exists because using the FBSDK or email/password I am able to safely instantiate the VC when the user is authorized (for these two the `instantiate` function is called on the `SignInViewController`. What seems to be the problem?

***UPDATE***

When opening the app, `TabViewController` is opened first. If there is no authorized user, `SignInViewController` will be instantiated:

```
// MARK: AUTO SIGN IN / CHECK IF USER IS LOGGED IN 
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    // user is not logged in
    if Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid == nil {
        do {
            try? Auth.auth().signOut()
        }
        let vc = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SignInViewController") as! SignInViewController
        self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you edit your question to show the `init` methods of your `SignInViewController`?  I suspect nothing is being loaded or allocated or instantiated before you attempt to call `instantiateTabVC()` on that object.

Comment: Updated. Thank you

Comment: I dont know if its related but I think you dont need `: UIViewController` in `instantiateTabVC ` method

Comment: I think your global variable should not be like this: `var signInViewController = SignInViewController()` instead  use this: `var signInViewController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SignInViewController") as! SignInViewController`

Comment: @3stud1ant3 the `TabViewController` is still nil. I don't think it made a difference

Comment: Have you changed the declaration of global variable `signInViewController`  like I mentioned above ?

Comment: @3stud1ant3 When I changed the global variable, I can't access the `instantiateTabVC` function because `var signInViewController` is no longer referring to the class where the function was declared

Comment: In which class `instantiateTabVC` is declared?

Comment: @3stud1ant3 in `SignInViewController`. I've updated my question to clarify that

Comment: Have you tried declaring it like I mentioned in the comment ? if yes then what is the error that xcode gives you. and if not please try once, I think you can access the `instantiateTabVC`

Comment: @3stud1ant3 I figured it out and posted my answer. Thank you for your help

Comment: did you checked user?.uid value , print this before you navigate to tabBar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. Because I'm very new to swift, I didn't know that you cannot segue from one `viewController` to another in the appDelegate(which I also tried to do). All I had to do was set the `rootViewController` after authorization:

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let initialViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "TabViewController")
self.window?.rootViewController = initialViewController
self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

It's amazing how simple this answer was. Thank you all who helped.